# Peewee circular foreign key dependencies exception

Tags: python, peewee

I'm trying to replicate Peewee example app using circular dependences as explained in [the docs](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#circular-foreign-key-dependencies), despite the creator clearly states this is usually a bad idea. This is the code mainly copied from the docs:

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase(None)

class BaseModel(Model):

class Meta:
    database = db

class User(BaseModel):
    username = CharField()
    # Tweet has not been defined yet so use the deferred reference.
    favorite_tweet = DeferredForeignKey('Tweet', null=True)

class Tweet(BaseModel):
    message = TextField()
    user = ForeignKeyField(User, backref='tweets')


db.init('twitter.db')
db.create_tables([User, Tweet])
User._schema.create_foreign_key(User.favorite_tweet) #Error
db.close()
```

I'm getting the an exception in the line commented with #Error. This line is needed, as explained in the docs:

> When you call create_table we will again encounter the same issue. For
>   this reason peewee will not automatically create a foreign key
>   constraint for any deferred foreign keys.
>
> To create the tables and the foreign-key constraint, you can use the
>   SchemaManager.create_foreign_key() method to create the constraint
>   after creating the tables.

This is the exception I get using Python 3.5.2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 2653, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "CONSTRAINT": syntax error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 23, in <module>
    User._schema.create_foreign_key(User.favorite_tweet)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 4930, in create_foreign_key
    self.database.execute(self._create_foreign_key(field))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 2666, in execute
    return self.execute_sql(sql, params, commit=commit)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 2660, in execute_sql
    self.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 2451, in __exit__    reraise(new_type, new_type(*exc_args), traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 178, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 2653, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
peewee.OperationalError: near "CONSTRAINT": syntax error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sqlite does not support ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT -- so when you're using Sqlite you should omit the additional call to create_foreign_key().

There is a clear NOTE in the docs that says:

> Because SQLite has limited support for altering tables, foreign-key constraints cannot be added to a table after it has been created.

Comment: I read that, but I was wondering if omitting that call means the deferred key is not created and thus the program could malfunction.

Comment: i'm not sure how you would even create such constraints in sqlite...it may not be possible due to the above.